# Get RMI server address from the stub

Tags: java, rmi

I have a java RMI server which exports itself with UnicastRemoteObject.export. Is there a way to find out the IP address that was embedded in the server stub?

Comment: I'm willing, but I have decided, I won't give further answers on RMI here because, you get down votes when you try to help.

Answer (score 0):

Your stub's default `toString` will return some info, something like this:

```
Test1[UnicastServerRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[172.30.235.40:53209](local),objID:[-79d153e9:13ff67a80cc:-7fff, -4560008469324700920]]]]
```